# Require explicit FTP over TLS with PHP

Tags: php, ssl, ftp

I'm trying to upload file to ftp with php. Only requirement from server's admin were Encryption should be `Require explicit FTP over TLS`. And that's it but I'm getting error `Warning: ftp_fput() [function.ftp-fput]: Can't open data connection.`. I manage to connect(in passive mode), but it fails to upload with any function(`ftp_put`, `ftp_nb_put`, `ftp_fput`). Error is the same all the times. I'm trying following code:

```
$host = 'ftps.someserver.net';
$user = '****';
$pass = '****';
$filename = "somefile.txt"


$dest_file = $filename;
$source_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $filename;

$fp = fopen($source_file, 'r');

$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($host, 21, 180);


if (ftp_login($ftp,$user,$pass)) {

    var_dump(ftp_pasv($ftp, true)); // gives me true
    // # first way
    // ftp_put($ftp, $dest_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);

    // # second
    // $ret = ftp_nb_put($ftp, $dest_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);

    // while (FTP_MOREDATA == $ret)
    // {
    //   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($ftp);
    // }

    // # third
    if (ftp_fput($ftp, $dest_file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) { // I was trying FTP_BINARY and FTP_ASCII.
        echo "Successfully uploaded\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while uploading\n";
    }       
}
ftp_close($ftp);
fclose($fp);
```

It works fine with my own ftp, that does not asks for explicit TLS. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you setup your TLS certificate on the server yet?

Comment: It's shared hosting, but it's has SSL certificate already installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ftp_pasv($ftp, TRUE);`. I found this in a [five year old comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php#93348) on php.net, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This one got me too. I discovered it was a bug with the version of PHP I was using (5.4.28). I tried the same script with PHP version 5.6.31 and everything worked.